# Help about trace of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm reading about Trace and Reject, which definition:

$Tr_M(U)= \sum \lbrace Im(h)|h\in Hom_R(U,M) \rbrace$

$Rej_M(U)= \bigcap \lbrace Ker(h)|h \in Hom_R(M,U)\rbrace$

So is that right:

> if $U_i$ are simple then $Tr_M(U_1\oplus...\oplus U_n)=Tr_M(U_1)\oplus...\oplus Tr_M(U_n) ?$

And if true, can I say that:

> Suppose $R$ is a right semisimple ring. Then $R_R$ is semisimple module and we have: $R_R=\oplus T_i$, which $T_i$ is simple. So $Tr_R(R_R)=Tr_R(\oplus T_i) \Rightarrow R_R=\oplus(Tr_R(T_i))$?